# Double Parameters in youtube embedding

Tags: html, iframe, youtube

i'm trying to embed this video for a project i'm doing on a NTB IPTV and I would like the controls to be hidden and the video to autoplay. Please consider the following:

```
<iframe width="853" height="480"
src="http://youtube.com/embed/3kSSpNpa4q0?autoplay=1?&autohide=2" 
frameborder="0" 
allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

Oh my bad, basically i cannot get these parameters to work in duality as soon as i used autohide autoplay stopped working.

Comment: nice Project and what is your specific question now?

Comment: Oh my bad, basically i cannot get these parameters to work in duality as soon as i used autohide autoplay stopped working.

*Bumped to Q*

Comment: how both will work in at a time?use any one of them? please ask your need properly

Comment: i'd say its pretty obvious, i want them to work in duality

Comment: this will not work, i did some researches and it is not possible... why do you want it like that? maybe there is another workaround? BTW autohide=1 will work

Comment: On the NTB there is no interaction so autoplay is required.Auto hide is wanted to provide a cleaner aesthetic

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/embed/3kSSpNpa4q0?autohide=1&enablejsapi=1&autoplay=1 the ´bar will be gone after 3 seconds, thats ok?

Answer (score 0):

Using Autoplay= 1 together with Autohide=2 is not possible.

But you could do

> https://www.youtube.com/embed/3kSSpNpa4q0?autohide=1&enablejsapi=1&autoplay=1

Which will trigger Autohide after 3 seconds